# web sockets for api

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I want to consume the API messages in c#.net and the response it may come continuously/frequently. Team suggest me to use Web sockets. But I consume the API thru HTTP. Can any one give idea which is better and advantages of Web-socket in continuous receiving the messages as well as in HTTP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP normally uses a request/response model. It does not allow the server to send data to the client, unless the client first requested it. This can be worked around by letting the client regularly poll the server, or by using the long polling technique where the server delays the response until data is available. In both cases, the client will need to regularly make a new request (though less often with long polling).

Web sockets remove these limitations so that polling or long polling is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with ASP.NET SignalR which able to send and receive messages via HTTP. You can achieve real-time web functionality to your messaging application. It's able to have server code push content to connected clients instantly, rather than having the server wait for a client to request new data.

Have a look at these samples -> http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.